# Decoding php "uniqid" function in order to render page

Tags: php, unique, decode

I want to encode `unique` in the page in which I am sending information to in other for the page to render.

In my `item.php` page I did this

```
$id = uniqid($row["ppid"]); //id
$sef = $row["Sef"]; //id

$qstr = http_build_query(array("Sef" => $sef, "ppid" => $id));
?>

<a href="<?php fetchdir($apages) ?>product.php?<?= $qstr ?>">View</a>
```

in my `view.php page`

```
if (isset($_GET['Sef']) && isset($_GET['ppid'])) {
    $id = $_GET["ppid"];
    $id2 = $_GET['Sef'];
```

The page would not render because the ppid is `uniqid`. Is there a way I can decode it in this page so that this page can render the info without the url losing the `uniqid` code?

Thank you for your time, comment and answers.

Comment: Not 100% sure what your asking, but .htacces mod_rewrite may help you

Comment: @Jonnny if a `ppid` of 1 and i use uniqid it will be like `151f80931ba1f9` so in my view.php it will get the `uniqid` instead of `1` and the page will not render.

Comment: @Jonnny if u think .htaccess can be of helo can u show me please

Comment: uniqid is not reversible encryption... I think you are barking up the wrong tree.

Comment: @Orangepill any idea how I can encrypt the ppid please?

Comment: @AlexRuso This should get you where you want...

Comment: @Orangepill i did see any link or answer. what did you mean please

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php ... sorry about that @AlexRuso

Comment: @Orangepill will i be able to encrypt the ppid in the url and decrypt in the other page with `mcrypt_encrypt`

Comment: Yes depending on which algorithm you use... some are just hashing algorithms.

Comment: @Orangepill can you show me an example for which one you think will work for my case please

Comment: [this example](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php#105173) should work for you.

Comment: @Orangepill so `encrypt` in the `item.php` page and `decrypt` in `view.php page`

Answer (score 0):

Based on your earlier questions, you are just trying to make the "raw" ppid less obvious.  Your "encode" step needs to be reversible, and you need a "decode" step that brings you back to the original ppid.

Currently your encode step is not reversible, and you have no decode step.

Here is a reversible version of the encode step:

```
$id = uniqid($row["ppid"]);
```

Here is a "decode" step for view.php that reverses the "encoding":

```
$id = substr($_GET["ppid"], 0, -13); // remove 13-character uniqid
```

This is not any more secure than using the raw ppid, but does make the product ID look more impressive.

Comment: thanks for your interest in this question, just to confuse somethings. In `item.php` page I use `$id = $row["ppid"] . uniqid($row["ppid"]);` and in `view.php` page I use `$id = substr($_GET["ppid"], 0, -13);` ? if so I have try it and it doesn't seem to work

Comment: I echo out the `$id` and if the pid is 1, it shows, `11` if its 2 it should `22`

Comment: because I have atleast 15 products in this table, it wouldnt work because anything over 9, it can not decode it. Btw, please change `-13` to `-14`.